# Testing accuracy is greater than Training accuracy

Tags: r, machine-learning

Well, this question is already asked multiple times here. But, all the answers are descriptive and I don't understand what to do at my case (as I am new at this sector). So, I have given all of my code here. I am practicing with this dataset: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Census+Income

```
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
library(e1071)

# Assigning column names
colNames = c ("age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "educationnum", 
              "maritalstatus", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "sex", 
              "capitalgain", "capitalloss", "hoursperweek", "nativecountry",
              "incomelevel")

# loading data
df <- read.table ('adult.data', header = FALSE, sep = ',', 
                          strip.white = TRUE, col.names = colNames, 
                          na.strings = '?', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Checking dim

```
dim(df)
```

Output:

```
[1] 32561    15
```

Too large, making it short (otherwise takes too much time at the time of applying algorithm):

```
df <- df[1:1200,]
```

Taking a look on our data

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1200 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ age          : int  39 50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 ...
 $ workclass    : Factor w/ 8 levels "Federal-gov",..: 7 6 4 4 4 4 4 6 4 4 ...
 $ fnlwgt       : int  77516 83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 ...
 $ education    : Factor w/ 16 levels "10th","11th",..: 10 10 12 2 10 13 7 12 13 10 ...
 $ educationnum : int  13 13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 ...
 $ maritalstatus: Factor w/ 7 levels "Divorced","Married-AF-spouse",..: 5 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 ...
 $ occupation   : Factor w/ 14 levels "Adm-clerical",..: 1 4 6 6 10 4 8 4 10 4 ...
 $ relationship : Factor w/ 6 levels "Husband","Not-in-family",..: 2 1 2 1 6 6 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ race         : Factor w/ 5 levels "Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 5 3 3 5 3 5 5 5 ...
 $ sex          : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ capitalgain  : int  2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
 $ capitalloss  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hoursperweek : int  40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
 $ nativecountry: Factor w/ 41 levels "Cambodia","Canada",..: 39 39 39 39 5 39 23 39 39 39 ...
 $ incomelevel  : Factor w/ 2 levels "<=50K",">50K": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
```

Removing useless/unimportant variables

```
df$fnlwgt <- NULL
```

Removing missing values

```
sum(df == '')
df[df == ''] <- NA
sum(!complete.cases(df))
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Splitting our dataset

```
trainingInst <- createDataPartition(df$incomelevel,p=0.8,list = FALSE)
trainingSet <- df[trainingInst,]
testingSet <- df[-trainingInst,]
```

Barplot for two datasets

```
barplot(table(trainingSet$incomelevel), xlab = 'Income Level', ylab = 'Frequency',
        main = 'Income Level at training dataset')
barplot(table(testingSet$incomelevel), xlab = 'Income Level', ylab = 'Frequency',
        main = 'Income Level at testing dataset')
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Building model

```
set.seed(291)
control <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', 
                        number=10, 
                        repeats=3, 
                        search='grid')

tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = (1:10)) 

rf.fit <- train(incomelevel ~ .,
            data = trainingSet,
            method = 'rf',
            metric = 'Accuracy',
            tuneGrid = tunegrid)
print(rf.fit)
```

Output:

```
> print(rf.fit)
Random Forest 

883 samples
 13 predictor
  2 classes: '<=50K', '>50K' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 883, 883, 883, 883, 883, 883, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
   1    0.7579655  0.0000000
   2    0.7579655  0.0000000
   3    0.7802265  0.1471624
   4    0.8156137  0.3628476
   5    0.8221829  0.4242543
   6    0.8269784  0.4616396
   7    0.8313258  0.4899318
   8    0.8323117  0.5017060
   9    0.8298249  0.4988749
  10    0.8266483  0.4917950

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 8.
```

Checking confusion Matrix

```
confusionMatrix.train(rf.fit)
```

Output:

```
> confusionMatrix.train(rf.fit)
Bootstrapped (25 reps) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)

          Reference
Prediction <=50K >50K
     <=50K  70.3 11.3
     >50K    5.4 12.9

 Accuracy (average) : 0.8323
```

Prediction:

```
testingSetPred <- predict(rf.fit,testingSet)
confusionMatrix(testingSetPred,testingSet$incomelevel)
```

Output:

```
> confusionMatrix(testingSetPred,testingSet$incomelevel)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction <=50K >50K
     <=50K   153   23
     >50K     13   31

               Accuracy : 0.8364          
                 95% CI : (0.7807, 0.8827)
    No Information Rate : 0.7545          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.002207        

                  Kappa : 0.5288          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.133614        

            Sensitivity : 0.9217          
            Specificity : 0.5741          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8693          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7045          
             Prevalence : 0.7545          
         Detection Rate : 0.6955          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.8000          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7479          

       'Positive' Class : <=50K
```

Accuracy for **training** is **0.8323** while accuracy for **testing** is **0.8364**. Well, here it's not bigger, in fact almost equal. But, at here, I fitted model with all features (`incomelevel ~ .,`); but at some cases, I haven't use all features. In that cases my training accuracy is same like this result (**0.8323**). But, testing accuracy is little bit higher (for example, **0.85**) So, why is this happening? Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong necessarily. It can happen

Comment: there is nothing wrong in testing accuracy being (slightly) greater than training accuracy. For example testing is done on less data than training and thus can easily result in greater accuracy

Comment: okay, I thought accuracy of testing is always less than accuracy of training data set. Out of topic, As I am beginner, I am asking for the suggestion. My objective of this practice is achieving higher accuracy for different types of machine learning models. Here, I am showing example with Random Forest algorithm/method. Is everything okay for this context?